# flutter text widget shows only the last entry

Tags: flutter, dart, date, calendar, containers

I am trying to create a calendar in flutter. Currently I am implementing the events. To test this I created a method that checks if there are events on the current date, which is when the rows are created. If this is the case, an x is printed in the container that represents the content. The whole thing is only a first test, whether it works in principle.
There is a problem when I create two events. The print output shows that both the first and the second event return a true. However, only the container with the second date is filled with an x.
I am not sure what the reason is or how to solve this.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

If more code is needed, I am happy to post it.

Container widget:

```
Widget contentContainer(DateTime actualDate) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        color: Colors.yellow.shade100,
      ),
      
      child: dateVergleich(actualDate) ? Text("X") : Text(''),
      width: 200,
      height: 40,
    );
  }
```

compare Method:

```
bool dateVergleich(DateTime tagesDatum) {
    final eventModelData = Provider.of<EventModelPro>(context);
    final eventModel = eventModelData.items;
    String tagesDatumString = DateFormat.yMd().format(tagesDatum);
    if (eventModel.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int x = 0; x < eventModel.length; x++) {
        //tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id.toString() ? Text('X') : Text('');
        if (tagesDatumString == eventModel[x].id.toString()) {
          vergleich = true;
        } else {
          vergleich = false;
        }
        print('____________');
        print(vergleich);
        print(tagesDatumString);
        print(eventModel[x].id.toString());
      }
```

print output:
[image]

the row is formed by two components:

List:

```
List<List<DateTime>> listeContent() {
      final List<List<DateTime>> gesamtContent = [];
      for (int i = 1; i <= anzahlColumns; i++) {
        final List<DateTime> row = [];
        for (int j = 1; j <= dateMonth; j++) {
          String actualDay;
          if (j < 10) {
            actualDay = changedDate.format('yyyy-MM-0$j');
          } else {
            actualDay = changedDate.format('yyyy-MM-$j');
          }
          DateTime dateTimeactualDay = DateTime.parse(actualDay);
          );
          row.add(dateTimeactualDay);
        }
        gesamtContent.add(row);
      }
      return gesamtContent;
    }
```

sticky Header:

```
return StickyHeadersTable(
        cellDimensions: CellDimensions.fixed(
          contentCellWidth: 100,
          contentCellHeight: 40,
          stickyLegendWidth: 100,
          stickyLegendHeight: 40,
        ),
        scrollControllers: _scrollController,
        columnsLength: listeColumns().length,
        rowsLength: listeRows().length,
        columnsTitleBuilder: (i) => columnContainer(listeColumns()[i]),
        rowsTitleBuilder: (i) => (currentDayMonthandYear == listeRows()[i])
            ? currentDayContainer(listeRows()[i], listeWeekday()[i])
            : rowContainer(
                listeRows()[i],
                listeWeekday()[i],
              ),
        contentCellBuilder: (i, j) =>
            //Text(listeContent()[i][j]),
            contentContainer(
              listeContent()[i][j],
            ),
        legendCell: Container()
        );
```

Comment: Can you provide the row that is implementing your contentContainer?

Comment: What is the rest of the `dateVergleich` function?  The code you've shown doesn't show it returning anything.  If, after exiting the `for`-loop, `dateVergleich` returns the value of `vergleich`, then it's returning whether the *last* event in the iteration matched, not whether *any* events matched.

Comment: i forgot the return statement of vergleich, but since the code doesn't work anyway, i won't fix that.
i understand why it doesn't work but can't come up with the solution how i can check against each event and show an "X" in the respective container of the date

Comment: @FirasAT I posted the components which are creating the row

Comment: You just need to make `dateVergleich` return `true` immediately when it finds a match and to return `false` if it finds no matches. (It's not very efficient though.  If you have a lot of elements, it'd be better to make a lookup table so that you don't need to iterate over all of the events for each `Container`.)

Comment: ok, thanks, how do I create a lookup table? Do you know, where I find an instruction?